# Nested Looping in MIPS X C Language

Tags: c

I am having issues in understanding the nested looping in MIPS and the codes on the internet are too complex to understand. Please help me to get this concept maybe using C language as I am well versed in it.

Answer (score 0):

My Nested Loop Code in MIPS:

```
li $t0, 0        # We store the value of constant from which the counting of the outer loop starts.  
 li $t1, 30      # We store the value of constant at which the counting of the outer loop ends.  
 
start_loop_1:  
 beq $t0, $t1, end_loop_1  

################# Start of code for Inner loop  
  li $t2, 0        # We store the value of constant from which the counting of the inner loop starts.  

  li $t3, 100      # We store the value of constant from which the counting of the inner loop ends.  

start_loop_2:  
  beq $t2, $t3, end_loop_2  
  addi $t2, $t2, 1    # In this statement we increment the counter by 1.  
  b start_loop_2  
end_loop_2:  
################ End of code for Inner loop  

  addi $t0, $t0, 1    # In this statement we increment the counter by 1.  
  b start_loop_1  
end_loop_1:
```

---

Its corresponding version in C Language:

```
for (int j=0; j<30; j++) {  
  for (int k=0; k<100; k++) {  
  }  
}
```

---

Explanation: To understand the concept of nested loops in mips for beginners, I have posted the most basic form of a nested  loop(for loop) specially to cater your query as you already mentioned that the complex codes available on the internet left you mind boggled. The above commented code will help you understand the process line by line. In order for us to apply loops , first we have to save the value of a starting number for a loop ie the number from which the iterations begin. As well as for the ending value at which the loop terminates in separate registers for each of the loops that we use in the process. Indentation is very important to be followed to help the reader understand the code. beq, bne, bgtz, bltz, bgez, blez are the only conditional branch opcodes . The ADDI instruction performs an addition on both the source register's contents and the immediate data,
and stores the result in the destination register.
It's syntax is:
ADDI $destination register's address, $source register's address, immediate data.
I hope this explanation proves to be fruitful to you. You are welcome to reply and ask if want to understand different variations and more complex codes involving nested loops and I will be happy to help. Please reply with an upvote if you got benefited by this code and explanation as it is what gives us confidence and motivation to keep giving our contributions in helping the global programming community.